# Binomial Coefficient Explanaition

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, proof-explanation, pattern-recognition

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $k\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$. Explain why it follows from

$$\binom nk=\frac{n}{1}\times\frac{n-1}{2}\times\frac{n-2}{3}\times\cdots\times\frac{n-k+1}{k}$$
that
$$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

We know $n! = n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)(n-k)!$. There are $k$ patterns in the product $n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$, namely $n-1+1$, $n-2+1$, $n-3+1$, $\ldots$ , $n-k+1$. A minor point to notice is that in the special case where $k = 0$, then it is a product of no factors, so its value is $1$. If $n - 0$, then $k$ can only be $0$, so again is a product of no factors and its value is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n}{1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n-2}{3}\cdot...\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k} = \frac{n}{1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n-2}{3}\cdot...\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k}\cdot\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k)!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$